# Substituir valores de colunas específicas por NA

Tags: r, funções, replace, apply

Gostaria de detectar e substituir valores acima de 6 em apenas algumas colunas de um data.frame por NA. Fiz a sintaxe assim, mas está dando erro... Alguém poderia me dar um help? Obrigado!

```
data <- apply(dados[14:128], 2, function(x) {x[x > 6] <- NA; x})
```

Comment: Consegui resolver usando data[,14:128][data[,14:128] > 6] <-NA

Answer (score 2):

Danilo, tudo bem?

Eu sugiro fazer da seguinte forma:

Criando um data frame para servir de exemplo:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
b <- c(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)

df <- data.frame(a,b)

> print(df)
    a  b
1   1 10
2   2  9
3   3  8
4   4  7
5   5  6
6   6  5
7   7  4
8   8  3
9   9  2
10 10  1
```

Uma forma de obter somente os valores maiores que 6 da coluna b, é a seguinte:

```
df$b[df$b > 6]
```

Então, basta aproveitar a mesma idéia e atribuir diretamente o valor desejado, que no seu caso é o NA:

```
df$b[df$b > 6] <- NA

> print(df)
    a  b
1   1 NA
2   2 NA
3   3 NA
4   4 NA
5   5  6
6   6  5
7   7  4
8   8  3
9   9  2
10 10  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Além da sua solução em comentário, que é completamente vetorizada, há outra também vetorizada que creio ser mais legível.

Primeiro um conjunto de dados exemplo.

```
set.seed(5139)    # Torna os resultados reprodutíveis
dados <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(20, 180, TRUE), 10))
```

Agora a tal solução. A função base R a usar é a função `is.na<-`. Esta função atribui o valor `NA` aos dados correspondentes aos índices do lado direito da função (que são um dos seus argumentos). Esses índices podem ser lógicos ou numéricos. Neste caso são índices lógicos.

```
is.na(dados[12:18]) <- dados[12:18] > 6
```

Fácil, é só isto.